# Creating and pushing to arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to create an array(if it does not already exist) and then push values to it.

```
foreach($playlist->items as $item) {
        $str = $item->snippet->title;
        $id = $item->snippet->resourceId->videoId;

        $substring = substr($str, 0, 5);
        $substring = strtolower($substring);

            if (is_array($substring)) {
                array_push($substring, $id);
            }
            else {
                $substring = array();
                array_push($substring, $id);
            } 
        array_push($artists, $substring);
    }
```

I am iterating through data retrieved from a Youtube playlist, so I go through each item with foreach which holds a 'title' - the artist and an 'id' - the video Id . I substring each title and try to use this to group artists into specific arrays.

If an array already exists for that artist, I try to push the 'id' onto the end of that array. If an array does not exist, I create one and then push the 'id' onto that array.

At the end I try to push each artist array into the 'artists' array.

What I get when I print out $artists array is something like this

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Gp8lDW2LUM0
    )

...

[543] => Array
    (
        [0] => Exa0CzlCb3Y
    )
```

Every single $id is in it's own array when they should be grouped together based on $substring. e.g

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [1] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [2] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [3] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [4] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => Gp8lDW2LUM0
        [1] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [2] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [3] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
    )
```

What am I not understanding?

Comment: As soon as I posted this, I had a realization. When I am checking is_array($substring) should I really be checking if there is an array that has the same name as $substring is holding and not the fact that $substring is an Array, where in fact it is a String..

Comment: first you make `$substring = strtolower($substring);` and after you lost the value  by `$substring = [];` Why?

Comment: For every item, if `$substring` isn't an array, you are pushing `$id` onto a blank array called `$substring` then pushing that array onto the `$artists` array. `$substring` is always going to be a string if you are running `substr()` and `strtolower()` on it, unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Answer to you comment - can't be a  string and an array with the same names, If you are thinking that may be such array, set a different name for the new string

Comment: you  need to replace a lot of $substring (which is a string) by $artists[$substring], even with that it will not work magically, you can also look at the syntax $arr[], wich does the same thing but creates the array if it doesn't exists

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simpler solution to your problem:

```
$artists = array();

foreach($playlist->items as $item) {
    $artist = $item->snippet->artist; // however the artist name is fetched..
    $id = $item->snippet->resourceId->videoId;

    $artists[$artist][] = $id
}
```

This way, you don't need to check if an artist is already in the array, it will do that automatically and append the video id to the artist.
The `$artists` array will be assosiative, I don't think you can do it with a numeric array.
The array will look like this:

```
Array
(
['Jon Lajoie'] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1_YUrdjLyAU
        [1] => lf3hflkap39
        [2] => 1vt1455zzbe
        [3] => 6dthg3drgjb
        [4] => jfop3ifjf3p
    )

['Lonely Island'] => Array
    (
        [0] => Gp8lDW2LUM0
        [1] => 5he5hj67j7r
        [2] => krt7tkktzk8
        [3] => we54w4ggsrg
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use substring as array key and do following:

```
**Remove**
if (is_array($substring)) {
                array_push($substring, $id);
            }
            else {
                $substring = array();
                array_push($substring, $id);
            } 
        array_push($artists, $substring);

**Replace**
     $artist[$substring][]=$id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I used this weird substring route because the titles of each video are not so easy to pull out an 'artist title'. E.g say I had a few David Bowie songs.  Their titles would be "David Bowie - Hetoes", "david bowie live 11/17/70", "david bowie official music video" etc. So with my substring i hoped it would pull out "david" for all three and be able to group them in the sane array

Comment: This is it! Thanks so much, that's all I needed to do, so simple